# Python3 - Printing user input on new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a list of names and their corresponding index number each on a new line. This is my current code:

```
nameList = input("Enter 3 names: ")
wordCount = len (nameList.split(' '))
print ("Your list contains", wordCount, "names.")

for index, element in enumerate(nameList, start=1):
    print("{}: {}".format(index, element))
```

and current output:

```
Enter 3 names: Tyler Gemma Alex
Your list contains 3 names.
1: T
2: y
3: l
4: e
5: r
6:  
7: G
8: e
9: m
10: m
11: a
12:  
13: A
14: l
15: e
16: x
```

How do I code it so that each name prints like this:

```
1. Tyler
2. Gemma
3. Alex
```

Answer (score 1):

You `split` it to count the words, but didn't keep the split version to iterate by word. Simple solution is to change:

```
nameList = input("Enter 3 names: ")
wordCount = len (nameList.split(' '))
```

to:

```
# Store list of names, not single string
nameList = input("Enter 3 names: ").split(' ')
wordCount = len(nameList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simpally:

```
a=input().split()
j=1
for i in a:
    print(str(j)+". "+i)
    j+=1
```

Output:

```
1. Tyler
2. Gemma
3. Alex
```